# Want to drop all rows containing some text

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove all rows containing TOTAL:

[image]

```py
data=pandas.read_excel(r'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\tax reports\sales_expense_regionwiseGST.xlsx')       
data2[data2.iloc[:,0].str.contains("Total".index)]
```

The following code to import and then selecting first column with `iloc` or using data['State/Union Territory')

`iloc` results in selecting the 1st column "type" as well, while `data['column_NAME_HERE']` ends up in error.

I want to fetch the rows and delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas` has vectorized string operations, so you can just filter out the rows that contain the string you don't want:

```
data[~data.<column_name>.str.contains("<your_text_here>")]
```

Another approach (if you have more than one string to filter):

```
data = data[~data['your column'].isin(['list of strings'])]
```

Comment: string contains space in it so. data[~data.State/Union Territory.str.contains("Total")] doesn't work. instead 

data[~data['State/Union Territory'].str.contains("Total")]

worked.. sorry for noobiness. thanks